# Invalid reference format docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im currently struggling to run a container and execute a command within this container.I'm trying to use NanoSNP (https://github.com/huangnengCSU/NanoSNP), which is an image available from dockerhub. After fulling this docker, the following command would be sufficient to run the the container:

```
docker run \
-v "${INPUT_DIR}":"${INPUT_DIR}" \
-v "${OUTPUT_DIR}":"${OUTPUT_DIR}" \
--gpus all \
huangnengcsu/nanosnp:v2.1-gpu \
run_caller.sh \
-b "${INPUT_DIR}/input.bam" \
-f "${INPUT_DIR}/reference.fa" \
-t "${THREADS}" \
-c "${COVERAGE}" \
-o "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
```

When trying to run the code: I get the following error: Invalid reference format.
This didn't happen before. When inactivating the `-v` it doesn't give the error again. I'm working with WSL, in VCS with a python script, and running my docker command via subprocess.run, so the following code looks like this (I only included the `-v` because that's where the error occurred:

```
subprocess.run(["sudo", "docker", "run", \
"-v", "${INPUT_DIR}",":","${INPUT_DIR}", \
"-v", "${OUTPUT_DIR}",":","${OUTPUT_DIR}", \
```

If anyone knows or sees the problem, let me know.

Comment: What are the values of the environment variables you use? Particularly INPUT_DIR and OUTPUT_DIR.

Comment: @HansKilian the following env variables are used: 
`INPUT_DIR= r"/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Code_SNP"    ## Absolute path
OUTPUT_DIR= r"/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Data"  ## Absolute path, make sure the output directory is existing.
THREADS="12"  ## number of threads used for computing.
COVERAGE="1"  ## coverage of sequencing reads`